# How do I create a Grails query for a many-to-many using primitives?

Tags: grails, join, hql, grails-orm

I have a POGO we'll call Foo and it has a list of Bars.  In the database, these are simple integers, but they're stored in a separate table (*Foo_Bars*)

```
class Foo {
    String name
    ...
    static hasMany = [bars:Integer]
    ...
}
```

So my question is, how do I create a query to find all Foos that with bars that are in a list.  I know how I would write it in SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM foo, foo_bars
WHERE foo.id = foo_bars.foo_id
AND foo_bars.bars_integer IN (11, 15, 52)
```

But I figure there must be a simpler way, using GORM or HQL.  How would I write this?

Answer (score 0):

but what exactly you want to achieve? list of Foo's where bars is equal to (11,15,52), or ONE OF bars is in the list or the list of bars contain each of given list?
either way, I doubt you can do it in criteria or using a dynamic finder, I'm trying to do it in an unit test and nothing worked

I would go with creating another domain class like

```
class FooBar {
    Foo foo
    Integer integer
}
```

which would create exactly the same database table as you already have, and then querying would be much simpler

Comment: I want where all the Bars in Foo match 11 AND 15 AND 52. The Foo could have more Bars in its collection, but that doesn't matter.